# How do I make a skin aware of changes of value of a hostComponent's property?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, skinning, flex-spark

I am writing a component and its skin. The skin has a `"selected"` state where it renders things with the corresponding glow.
It so happens that the *being selected* state is held at a property in the `hostComponent`, which is set/unset externally (not by a direct user interaction on the skin).

I tried making this `boolean` property of the `hostComponent` a `SkinPart`, and at skin initialization set up a `ChangeWatcher` on this property that would trigger the state change. No cigar. :(

What's the way to make the skin's state change through the `hostComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What's the way to make the skin's state change through the hostComponent?
```

Call invalidateSkinState() in your hostComponent's property.

That will in turn force commitProperties to rerun during the next render event which will in turn force getCurrentSkinState() to re-run when commitProperties runs.

Make sure that your hostComponent implements getCurrentSkinState() and returns the string value representing the state you want to go to.